# Global existence and uniqueness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As a graduate student in economics, I kindly ask for your assistance in understanding this theorem in the simplest way possible:

The professor's notes present the global existence and uniqueness theorem as follows:

Consider the initial value problem (IVP):

\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=F(t,x) \quad x(t_0)=x_0
\end{equation}
Suppose that $F(t,x)$ and $F'_x(t,x)$ are continuous for all $(t,x)$. Suppose too that there exist continuous functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ such that
\begin{equation}
A: \quad |F(t,x)| \le a(t) |x| + b(t) \quad \text{for all }(t,x)
\end{equation}
Given an arbitary point $(t_0,x_0)$, there exists a unique solution $x(t)$ of the IVP defined on $(- \infty, + \infty)$. If the condition above is replaced by the weaker condition
\begin{equation}
B: \quad x F(t,x) \le a(t) |x|^2 + b(t) \quad \text{for all }t \ge t_0
\end{equation}
then the IVP has a unique solution defined on $[t_0, +\infty)$.

If I understand correctly, Condition $A$ imposes a bound on the growth of the function $F(t,x)$ in terms of $|x|$, ensuring that the function does not grow too rapidly as $|x|$ increases. This condition says that the rate of change of $x$, given by $F(t,x)$, is bounded by a linear function of $|x|$, plus some additional term that might depend on $t$. Is that correct?

Why condition B is weaker than A?

Then, the prof slides make the following remark:

Condition $A$ is satisfied if there exists a continuous function $c(t)$ such that
\begin{equation}
C: \quad |F'_x(t,x)| \le c(t) \quad \text{for all }(t,x)
\end{equation}
In fact, by the mean value theorem, for some $\delta$ in $[0,x]$ we have:
\begin{equation}
F(t,x) - F(t,0) = F'_x (t, \delta) x
\end{equation}
and $C$ implies that $|F(t,x)| = |F'_x (t, \delta) x + F(t,0)| \le |F'_x (t, \delta)| |x| + |F(t,0)| \le a(t) |x| + b(t)$ if we let $a(t) = c(t) $ and $b(t) = |F(t,0)|$.

I didn't quite grasp the meaning of this remark. Can you provide some clarification?

Comment: The remark is saying that you could check condition (C) instead of condition (A), because if condition (C) is true, then condition (A) is also true.